# in text citation for handbook

Tags: mla, citations

I want to do ***in text citation*** of my "DK Handbook", 
In other words, I don't want put it's citation in 'work cited' section as it would be short and so obvious

I searched internet and MLA handbook but foud nothing,

I am wondering can someone help me to cite it in MLA format:

it is a DK-Handbook second edition & custom edition for my college and published by Longman (I don't know whether I should mention publisher in 'in text citation') and I want to cite page 85 which is in third chapter

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to write both the citation (marked up either with quotes or italics) and its reference with the natural flow, making them visually distinct but semantically following the flow of text seamlessly:

> As the DK-Handbook recommends, *you need to give readers
>   information about the source.* How exactly you present the source depends on how much focus you want to draw to it, as opposed to the quote itself.
>
> If you're writing about the source, and use quotes as some kind of teaser, to incite the reader to try the source, make sure to present the source clearly. Conversely, if the quote is self-contained, self-explanatory and you just give the source out of common courtesy, just give enough information that the reader will be able to trace the quotation, even if it takes some considerable effort.